# javascript - Chart.js change x unit to add Data

Tags: javascript

First time using chart.js.
There are many good features, but we are having difficulty with the contents below.

```
            chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type   : 'line',
                data   : {
                    labels  : category,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "data1",
                            data : data1
                        },
                        {
                            label: "data2",
                            data : data2
                        },
                        {
                            label: "data3",
                            data : data3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit          : 'hour',
                                displayFormats: {
                                    second: 'HH:mm:ss',
                                    minute: 'HH:mm',
                                    hour  : 'HH'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            
            
    function addChartData(label, newData) {
        chart.data.labels.push(label);
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            Object.keys(newData).forEach(type => {
                if (type === dataset.label) {
                    dataset.data.push(newData[type]);
                }
            });
        });

        if(chart.data.datasets[0].data.length > 24){
            chart.data.labels.shift();
            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                dataset.data.shift();
            });
        }
       
        chart.update();
    }
```

I want to leave the existing x data as 'hour' and change it to 'second' only for the added data.
I tried this code but this was a code that changed the unit of the whole x.

```
 chart.options.scales.x.time.unit = 'second';
//or
chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'second';
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the addChartData function to handle the different time units for the existing and new data. You can try the following modified code:

chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
labels: category,
datasets: [
{
label: "data1",
data: data1
},
{
label: "data2",
data: data2
},
{
label: "data3",
data: data3
}
]
},
options: {
scales: {
x: {
type: 'time',
time: {
unit: 'hour',
displayFormats: {
second: 'HH:mm:ss',
minute: 'HH:mm',
hour: 'HH'
}
}
}
}
}
});

function addChartData(label, newData) {
chart.data.labels.push(label);

```
chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    Object.keys(newData).forEach(type => {
        if (type === dataset.label) {
            if (dataset.data.length === chart.data.labels.length - 1) {
                // Existing data, keep 'hour' as time unit
                dataset.data.push(newData[type]);
            } else {
                // Added data, change time unit to 'second'
                dataset.data.push({
                    t: label,
                    y: newData[type]
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.length > 24) {
    chart.data.labels.shift();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.shift();
    });
}

if (chart.data.labels.length > 0) {
    const lastLabel = chart.data.labels[chart.data.labels.length - 1];
    if (lastLabel !== label) {
        // Update x-axis time unit for the newly added data
        chart.options.scales.x.time.unit = 'second';
    } else {
        // Revert to 'hour' for existing data
        chart.options.scales.x.time.unit = 'hour';
    }
}

chart.update();
```

}

This code checks whether the current label being added is the last label in the chart. If it is, it sets the x-axis time unit to 'second' for the newly added data; otherwise, it reverts to 'hour' for existing data.

Comment: It's not working. T.T
But thank you for your answer.